# svn command fail from Maven

Tags: svn, maven

I have imported a project with Maven that has a module using STP-SCA Tools. The [POM](http://websvn.ow2.org/filedetails.php?repname=frascati&path=/trunk/org.eclipse.stp.sca.model/pom.xml) of this module tries to download the STP-SCA Tools by SVN.

When I do a `mvn install` of this `POM.xml` I get the following on cmd

```
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-scm-plugin:1.6:checkout (checkout) @ sca-model ---
[INFO] Removing C:\WorkSpace\FrascatiTrunk\org.eclipse.stp.sca.model\org.eclipse
.stp.sca\target\checkout
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "svn --non-interactive checkout svn://dev.eclips
e.org/svnroot/soa/org.eclipse.stp.sca-tools/org.eclipse.stp.sca/tags/3.5SR1/org.
eclipse.stp.sca C:\WorkSpace\FrascatiTrunk\org.eclipse.stp.sca.model\org.eclipse
.stp.sca\target\checkout"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\WorkSpace\FrascatiTrunk\org.eclipse.stp.sca.model\o
rg.eclipse.stp.sca\target
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The svn command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] "svn" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.778s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Oct 01 16:30:13 CEST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/108M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-scm-plugin:1.6:che
ckout (checkout) on project sca-model: Command failed.The svn command failed.
```

If I try that svn dir on Eclipse it works.

Why does the svn command fail from Maven?

Answer (score 2):

The command that is failing for you is

`svn --non-interactive checkout svn://dev.eclipse.org/svnroot/soa/org.eclipse.stp.scatools/org.eclipse.stp.sca/tags/3.5SR1/org.eclipse.stp.sca C:\WorkSpace\FrascatiTrunk\org.eclipse.stp.sca.model\org.eclipse.stp.sca\target\checkout`

and it fails with `"svn" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.`

Now I don't speak that language myself, but I'll bet it is saying that command "svn" was not recognized.

Basically, what you need to do is you need to install & configure an SVN client so that you can run `svn` from the command line.

Comment: thx @eis, I thought tortoise was enough but I just downloaded silksvn for command line.